# Encrypting env file in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, encryption, redis, environment-variables

I need a lil help with my NextJs application. I am using redis along with NextJs application. To establish redis connection, redis password and some api key are stored in an env file.

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY=""
NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIS_PASSWORD=""
```

How should I encrypt that env file and then decrypt it during runtime, I have seen few libraries that encrypt file using passphrase but then the passphrase still remains in the code, which I feel takes away the encryption purpose.

**Can someone let me know what is the best practice here? Any help/lead would be highly appreciated!!**

Comment: There's no use encrypting environment variables that you're sending to the browser. If they get used in the browser, you'll have to include something to decrypt them, making your encryption useless. If you're not using them in the browser, just don't send them (remove `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix). On the server-side (not public variables), there isn't really a need to encrypt them

Comment: Devs do encrypt their credentials right? Where they encrypt their credentials using a passphrase on cli and store it in .enc file.  I was looking to implement the same thing. How safe it is to store api keys for services in env file, even though used on server side.

Comment: You need to ask yourself, "do I really want the browser accessing my database remotely?"  This is why we have a back-end/front-end separation.  The browser should mostly be stupid, making requests to the server for the information it needs, so the credentials can all live in the secure server.  That way, you can change the database without rewriting your front-end.

Comment: *Devs do encrypt their credentials right?* - I've never seen anything like this done before, and I can't really see the point. It'd become a similar situation as the browser then; if a user has server access to get the encrypted password, they almost certainly also have access to the code that can decrypt it (even more likely when that code is JavaScript)

Comment: If you don't prefix with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` it's perfectly safe (note that this only applies to Next.js to any future readers). The env file does not get sent to the browser. Instead, references to public environment variables are replaced as strings during the build phase. Next.js will not do this replacement for variables not marked as public

Comment: _Devs do encrypt their credentials right?_ If one does, perhaps only for including the variable values in version control.